# fragmented urls causing problems in SEO

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, seo

First of all I want to tell that I don't know my question is correct or not but I have searched google and SO for this answer but didn't find anything.

Try to explain my problem
I am making a website which is in php a server side scripting language and html css jquery and few other libraries.
It contains may pages and in few pages it contains a form which I am submitting using ajax.

Now When the person who is doing SEO for the website analyzes it by using some tool (A1 site map generator) it find outs some unwanted urls like:

```
https://wwww.example.com/graphic-design?_escaped_fragment_=
```

and

```
https://wwww.example.com/graphic-design#!
```

this problem shows on those pages which contains the ajax form.

can anyone explain me what is the cause I am seeing this and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your ajax request. I had this problem too may be your sending data through get in your ajax form. change ajax's get to post.